# creating variable dynamically inside optimization function scipy

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, tensor

The below code is for finding the minimum errors in approximating tensor unfold with three matrices a, b, c. Optimization is carried using variables a, b, c.

I am new to optimization case so please help me out in understanding this. My queries are:

1. inside f, how can we use a, b, c value at each iteration.
2. How can we create a variable for `khatri_rao` product using a, b, c for each iteration.
3. For each iteration, values of `params[0]/[1]/[2]` are not 2D array values. Not even initial values are seen? My code's error talks about which tuple?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.append("../tensorly-master/")
import tensorly as tl

def f(params, t0, t1, t2):#arguments are tensor unfold
    a, b, c= params[0], params[1], params[2]#multi variables in optimization
    #norm of tensor unfold mode0 minus "a" matrix multiplied with transpose of ' khatri rao product of "c" & "b" '
    value0= t0 - np.matmul(a, tl.tenalg.khatri_rao([c, b], reverse=False).T)
    value1= t1 - np.matmul(b, tl.tenalg.khatri_rao([a, c], reverse=False).T)
    value2= t2 - np.matmul(c, tl.tenalg.khatri_rao([b, a], reverse=False).T)
    #sum of all norms
    values=np.linalg.norm(value0, "fro")+np.linalg.norm(value1, "fro")+np.linalg.norm(value2, "fro")
    #optimizing the sum of all norms be minimum
    return values

#randomly initialinzing tensor , three arrays and unfolding tensor
tn=np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(3,3,3))
a=np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(3,2))
b=np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(3,2))
c=np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(3,2))
t0=tl.unfold(tn, 0)
t1=tl.unfold(tn, 1)
t2=tl.unfold(tn, 2)
#optimization
result=optimize.minimize(f, [a, b, c], args=(t0, t1, t2))
if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

the error is:

```
error:-
Using numpy backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stc.py", line 27, in <module>
    result=optimize.minimize(f, [a, b, c], args=(t0, t1, t2))
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 597, in minimize
    return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 963, in _minimize_bfgs
    gfk = myfprime(x0)
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 293, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 723, in approx_fprime
    return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 657, in _approx_fprime_helper
    f0 = f(*((xk,) + args))
  File "/home/manish/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 293, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "stc.py", line 10, in f
    value0= t0 - np.matmul(a, tl.tenalg.khatri_rao([c, b], reverse=False).T)
  File "../tensorly-master/tensorly/tenalg/_khatri_rao.py", line 70, in khatri_rao
    n_columns = matrices[0].shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: 1.shape` is a tuple.  That `shape[1]` raises this error means that shape has only one element, so `matrices[0]` must be 1d (or even 0d).  I don't anything about `tensorly`, `tl.tenalg.khatri_rao` is receiving the wrong dimensioned inputs.  Have you tested `f()` to make sure it can be call with the initial parameters?

Comment: min ||t0 - a(c\*b)^T ||_f + ||t1 - b(a\*c)^T ||_f + ||t2 - c(b\*a)^T ||_f  where a, b, c are variable and matrices of 3X2 and t0, t1, t2 are matrices of 3X9 , * is khatri-rao product (not mulitplication) and ^T is transpose and _f is frobenius norm. I new to writing optimization function for this where function contains calling a function for khatri-rao in each iteration. Standalone this "f" function gives result. Am i incorrectly modelling the mathematical eq in code?

Comment: I would add a diagnostic print to `f` to verify the nature of the `a`,`b`,`c` variables it gets.  What's their shape?  `dtype`?  In other words, make sure you understand what `minimize` is passing to your function.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, params is a 1D array which is needed to be modified accordingly before assigning to a, b, c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optimize` calls the `f` function by passing a 1D array (shape (n,)), even if the given initial guess is not that shape (see for instance in [`_minimize_bfgs`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L953) ). You could use `reshape` and [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to reconstruct the correct 2D arrays `a`, `b` and `c` from the 1D array `params`:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np
import tensorly as tl

def f(params, t0, t1, t2): # arguments are tensor unfold
    a, b, c = np.split(x0.reshape(3, 6), 3, axis=1)  # unpack the variables

    # norm of tensor unfold mode0 minus "a" matrix 
    # multiplied with transpose of ' khatri rao product of "c" & "b" '
    value0= t0 - np.matmul(a, tl.tenalg.khatri_rao([c, b], reverse=False).T)
    value1= t1 - np.matmul(b, tl.tenalg.khatri_rao([a, c], reverse=False).T)
    value2= t2 - np.matmul(c, tl.tenalg.khatri_rao([b, a], reverse=False).T)
    #sum of all norms
    values = np.linalg.norm(value0, "fro") + \
             np.linalg.norm(value1, "fro") + \
             np.linalg.norm(value2, "fro")

    # optimizing the sum of all norms be minimum
    return values

# randomly initializing tensor, three arrays and unfolding tensor
tn = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(3,3,3))
t0 = tl.unfold(tn, 0)
t1 = tl.unfold(tn, 1)
t2 = tl.unfold(tn, 2)

# Initial guess :
a = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(3,2))
b = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(3,2))
c = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=(3,2))

x0 = np.hstack([a, b, c]).ravel()

# optimization
result = optimize.minimize(f, x0, args=(t0, t1, t2))

if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

Comment: It's awesome to have a "free" solver. At the same time, the hoops are real... :D